# Mixed arithmetic between custom types and scala inbuilt numbers - is it possible?

Tags: scala, numbers, implicit-conversion

Is it possible to create one's own numeric types which can be compared with inbuilt scala numeric types, and possibly used in mixed arithmetic?
For example, assuming

```
class UnsignedInt(private val bits :Int) extends AnyVal {
    ...
}
```

Can I make it equal to `Int`s?
While I can define `def ==(that :Int)` (which I think shouldn't be possible), I can't find anyway to force a conversion so that

```
val (s, u) = 1 -> new UnsignedInt(1)
s == u
```

yields true after invoking my custom comparison instead of the compiler giving up before even it's run. I am aware of the dangars of mixed arithmetics in general, but as such comparison doesn't produce compilation errors and will often be intuitively written, I'd like to at least be able to promote both operands to a type they can be safely injected in.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this in Scala is using implicit conversion; [this blog post](https://tomjefferys.blogspot.com/2011/11/implicit-conversions-in-scala.html) explains it well. Porting that idea to your class would be:

```
object UnsignedIntImplicits {
   implicit def Int2UnsignedInt(value:Int) = new UnsignedInt(value) 
}
```

Then be sure to activate it with:

```
import UnsignedIntImplicits._
```